# How to get buyer's info in PayPal Mobile SDK

Tags: android, mobile, paypal, sdk

I am using PayPal Mobile SDK for Android and am wondering how I can get the buyer's info in my app after a payment is successful.

Looking at the onActivityResult() method in https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md the "confirm" object seems to have info of the seller, amount paid, currency, state, etc but I haven't been able to find out how I can get buyer's info, e.g. email, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you Verify a Mobile payment, you are doing a lookup of the Payment Resource.  What you get back in the response of that lookup, is what you'll have available for buyer information from that particular transaction.  More information on the payment resource lookup can be found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#look-up-a-payment-resource).

Comment: Thank you. That helped. I was able to get hints from your reference, and also from [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/) and [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/#looking-up-a-payment-using-the-rest-api).